# Grails and Gradle not Importing in Intellij 14.1 CE

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a grails 3.0.9 app that I am trying to import in IntelliJ. I did it before and it works but now it is not recognising anything.

Here is what I follow:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/importing-project-from-gradle-model.html

But I do not get anything that ressembles to a grails project.
Here is a screenshot of my project files left side bar:

[image]

What is that supposed to mean?
Why can't it just import it by using my build.gradle file and get it done with so I can run my grails app?

Answer (score 0):

Intellij Ultimate does what you want, JetBrains don't support grails in the CE edition.